# How to get all indexes of a value that occurs multiple times in a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a long list where each element can be a number between 1 and 30 and I need to get the indexes of all 1's, all 2's, all 3's... right up to 30. I thought I could just use index() and loop across the 30, but it seems like the function only looks for the first occurrence of the element specified. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: check `enumerate`

Comment: Please post the code that attempts to "loop across the 30".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
dct = {}
for j in range(1,31):
    dct[j] = [i for i, x in enumerate(long_list) if x == j]
```

Comment: @DavidH, welcome bro :)))

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using the `enumerate`.

The example code is as below:

```
for j in range(1, 30):
    print([i for i, e in enumerate([1,5,25,30]) if e == j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do able to use the `index` method.  The index method accepts also the starting position from which it begins to look for the specified element (as noted in the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). It can be done as follows:

```py
def index_all(x, l):
    indices = []
    start = 0
    while start < len(l):
        try:
            i = l.index(x, start)
            indices.append(i)
            start = i + 1
        except ValueError:
            break

    return indices
```

However, if you have multiple values to look for, and not only one, this not might be the optimal way to do this, as you can get the indices of all elements in a single run. The above code achieve this for the general case, even if not all the elements in the list are required.

```py
def index_many(values, l):
    indices = {v: [] for v in values}
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x in indices:
            indices[x].append(i)

    return indices
```